# Set::write: Error When Creating Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm very new to Mathematica, and I'm getting pretty frustrated with the errors I'm generating when it comes to creating a function. Below, I have a function I'm writing for 'centering' a matrix where rows correspond to examples, columns to features. The aim is to subtract from each element the mean of the column to which it belongs.

```
centerdata[datamat_] := (

  numdatapoints = 
   Dimensions[datamat][[1]](*Get number of datapoints*)

     numberfeatures = 
    Dimensions[datamat[[1]]][[1]](*Get number of datapoints*)

      columnmean = ((Total[datamat])/numdatapoints)

      For[i = 1, i < numdatapoints + 1, i++, (* For each row*)

       For[j = 1, j < numfeatures + 1, j++, (* For each element*)

              datum = datamat[[i]][[j]];
         newval = (datum - (colmean[[j]]));
         ReplacePart[datamat, {i, j} -> newval];
         ];
       ];

  Return[datamat];
  )
```

Running this function for a matrix, I get the following error:

"Set::write: Tag Times in 4 {5.84333,3.054,3.75867,1.19867} is Protected. >>
Set::write: "Tag Times in 4\ 150 is Protected."

Where {5.84333,3.054,3.75867,1.19867} is the first example in the data matrix and 150 is the number of examples in the matrix (I'm using the famous [iris dataset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set), for anyone interested). These errors correspond to this code:

```
numdatapoints = Dimensions[datamat][[1]](*Get number of datapoints*)

numberfeatures = Dimensions[datamat[[1]]][[1]](*Get number of datapoints*)
```

Googling and toying with this error hasn't helped much as the replies in general relate to multiplication, which clearly isn't being done here.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `;` at the end of each command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a table (`tab`) of data the function `Mean[tab]` will return a list of the means of each column.  Next, you want to subtract this (element-wise) from each row in the table, try this:

```
Map[Plus[-Mean[tab],#]&,tab]
```

I have a feeling that there is probably either an intrinsic statistical function to do this in one statement or that I am blind to a much simpler solution.

Since you are a beginner I suggest that you immediately read the documentation for:

- `Map`, which is one of the fundamental operators in functional programming languages such as Mathematica pretends to be; and
- *pure functions* whose use involves the cryptic symbols `#` and `&`.

If you are writing loops in Mathematica programs you are almost certainly mis-using the system.